# How to get a has_many relationship with a different where criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following classes for Headers and Items and would like to get all items that are only is_deleted=false and disregard the is_enabled (or get either true / false since is_enabled is a Boolean):

```
class Header < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :conditions => 'items.is_deleted=false and items.is_enabled=true', :order => 'position'
  ...
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :header
  ....
 end

h290=Header.find(290)
h290.items # 2 item
h290.items.where('is_enabled=false')  # and's them to (items.is_deleted=false and items.is_enabled=true) AND (is_enabled=false) ORDER BY position
```

Is there a way to say disregard the is_enabled=true or make it so that the where above is or'd such that:
`(items.is_deleted=false and items.is_enabled=true) OR (items.is_deleted=false and items.is_enabled=false) ORDER BY position`

perhaps a different has_many like:

```
  has_many :all_items, :conditions => 'items.is_deleted=false', :order => 'position', :class_name=>'item'
```

but this doesn't seem to work - perhaps just a syntax issue.

What is the best way to get either state for enabled for items? Can I filter my items for having is_enabled being true or false? Maybe just a method like this but it would seem preferable to have this as part of the relationship:

```
class Header < ActiveRecord::Base
...
def all_items
  Item.where('header_id=? and is_deleted=false',self.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One option can be by use of scope:

```
class Header < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :deleted, joins(:items) & Item.deleted
  scope :enabled, joins(:items) & Item.enabled    
  ## Other way to write the same thing:
  #scope :enabled, joins(:items).merge(Item.enabled)
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :deleted, lambda { where("is_deleted=false") }
  scope :enabled, lambda { where("is_enabled=true ") }
end
```

You can use these scopes to get the desired results using suitable filters.

or other approach can be to write a filter function in `Header` and use that with association:

```
class Header < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :order => 'position'

...
def deleted
  where('items.is_deleted=false')
end
```

With this you can get the results by: `@header.deleted.items`

Have a look at [Advanced Queries in Rails 3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3), You may get more appropriate ideas.